# How to stop windows startup python script

Tags: python, windows, startup

I have a python script called forever.py that I am running via windows local group policy editor. The script is positioned in the directory `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup`. Here is that script,

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
import logging.config

# Makes server_receiver.py run forever unless there is an error with this script

LOGGER_NAME = 'STARTUP_RECEIVER'
logging.config.fileConfig('C:\\Automation\\startup\\config\\startup_receiver.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)


while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', r'C:\Automation\startup\hello.py'],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    rc = p.returncode
    if rc != 0:
        logger.debug('{}'.format(error))
        sleep(5)
        continue
    else:
        logger.debug('Test Passed with return code {}'.format(rc))
        sleep(5)
        pass
```

The script just runs another python script called `hello.py` which prints `hello`. Since this script begins at startup and runs in the background, I was wondering if there was any way I could add anything into the script or into another script that would allow me to kill forever.py. My thought is that since this script is running in the background, I cannot use argparse to add an option called let's say '-stop' that will  kill the current pid. The only other solution that comes to mind is to kill this script with another script, which I'm not certain how I'd do that. I don't believe there is another way to get the pid of another running script like there is in linux.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can do here? Also, there may be some permission issues because the startup scripts directory is loaded in C:\windows\system32.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. Delete the script?

Comment: Kill as an put an end to the process. My script continuously runs that hello.py script even when there is an error. It waits 5 seconds and runs the hello.py again. Say I notice after a few hours that this is happening and I want to stop (kill) the script. I can't easily do that unless I go into my local group policy editor and remove the script from my startup folder then restart my pc. I'm looking for a way around this. Sort of like systemctl start/stop commands on linux